# How is the grouping done in groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'key':['A','B','C','A','B','C'],
                'data1':range(6), 'data2': rng.randint(0,10,6)}, columns=['key','data1','data2'])

l=[0,1,0,1,2,0]
df.groupby(l).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

So the output of your code is
https://ibb.co/kgXSwvL

We have three distinct values 0,1,2 in the *list l*.

If you see carefully it's the sum of values in *data1* column on the same index where 0 is encountered.
For Example, in the given list l, 0 is at 0th, 2nd and 5th position where *data1* has values 0, 2, 5 which sums up to 7 and *data2* has values 3, 5, 2 which sums up to 10.

and similarly for value 1, in the list l, 1 is at index 1 and 3, hence the value corresponding to *data1* in the dataframe df for the label 1 and 3 is 1 and 3 respectively which sums up to 4.

Similarly for value 3 in the list the answer can be verified.